# How do I use pytest fixture dependencies and params at the same time?

Tags: python, pytest, parameterized-unit-test

I'm trying to create a fixture that has dependencies on other fixtures and is also parameterized. Example:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def fix1():
  ...

@pytest.fixture(scope="module", params=[False, True])
def fix2(fix1, param):
  ...
```

which gives me the error: `fixture 'param' not found`.

I've tried using a default arg

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="module", params=[False, True])
def fix2(fix1, param=True):
  ...
```

but this just ends up with the fixture always receiving `True` no matter the parameter. `@pytest.mark.parameterize(..., indirect=True)` on the test also just ends up with the same result as the above.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`request`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/fixture.html#fixture-parametrize) as the fixture function's argument, and then its property `param` to get the value:

```py
@pytest.fixture(scope="module", params=[False, True])
def fix2(fix1, request):
    print(request.param)
    ...
```